# Which SendAsync method is called when a HttpClientHandler is passed to HttpClient

Tags: c#, httpclient, .net-4.5

Most of the properties for customizing requests are defined in `HttpClientHandler`, this class is a subclass of `HttpMessageHandler`, the class defined like this:

```
public abstract class HttpMessageHandler : IDisposable
{
  protected internal abstract Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync
    (HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
  public void Dispose();
  protected virtual void Dispose (bool disposing);
}
```

The book `<C#5.0 in a nutshell>` said the `SendAsync` method in `HttpMessageHandler` is called when we call `HttpClient`'s `SendAsync` method. But the `HttpClient` class also defines a `SendAsync` method, when we call this method on an instance of `HttpClient`, which `SendAsync` is called?

Comment: To summarize your question: HttpClient has a method SendAsync. HttpMessageHandler has a method SendAsync (overriden by HttpClientHandler). HttpClient.SendAsync calls HttpMessageHandler.SendAync. What's the problem?

Comment: Do you mean HttpClient.SendAsync calls HttpMessageHandler's SendAsync method, not its own?

Comment: When you call HttpClient.SendAsync, then HttpClient.SendAsync is executed. When HttpClient.SendAsync is executed, it calls HttpMessageHandler.SendAsync.

Comment: @AllenLi-AI3 Read [abstract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5(v=vs.71).aspx) and [override](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3(v=vs.71).aspx) from MSDN.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what's happening essentially:

*HttpMessageInvoker & HttpClient*

```
class HttpMessageInvoker
{
    private HttpMessageHandler handler;

    public HttpMessageInvoker(HttpMessageHandler handler)
    {
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    public virtual void SendAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("HttpMessageInvoker.SendAsync");
        this.handler.SendAsync();
    }
}

class HttpClient : HttpMessageInvoker
{
    public HttpClient(HttpMessageHandler handler)
        : base(handler)
    {
    }

    public override void SendAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("HttpClient.SendAsync");
        base.SendAsync();
    }
}
```

*HttpMessageHandler & HttpClientHandler*

```
abstract class HttpMessageHandler
{
    protected internal abstract void SendAync();
}

class HttpClientHandler : HttpMessageHandler
{
    protected internal override void SendAync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("HttpClientHandler.SendAsync");
    }
}
```

So if you call `SendAsync` on an `HttpClient` instance, that method is executed. The method calls the `SendAsync` method from `HttpMessageInvoker`. This method calls the `SendAsync` method of a `HttpMessageHandler` instance. `HttpMessageHandler` is abstract; `HttpClientHandler` provides a concrete implementation of the abstract `SendAync` method by overriding it.

*Example:*

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
var client = new HttpClient(handler);
client.SendAsync();
```

*Output:*

```
HttpClient.SendAsync
HttpMessageInvoker.SendAsync
HttpClientHandler.SendAsync
```